# Creating a C string macro with SCons

Tags: c, scons

To create macros with SCons this seems to work for integers:
`env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["MY_NUMBER_MACRO={0}".format(0))`

Trying something similar with strings:
`env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["MY_STRING_MACRO={0}".format("Joe"))`

yields the following build error:
`'joe' undeclared first use in this function) gcc [Ln 1, Col 24]`

How do you properly delcare a string macro with SCons?

Comment: Try `"\"Joe\""` ?

Comment: ``` "\'Joe\'"``` worked!
``` "\"Joe\"" ``` did not. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-CPPDEFINES

A dictionary can specify the value being defined (key) and the value to set it to (value)
Basically

```
env.Append(CPPDEFINES={"MY_STRING_MACRO":"{0}".format("Joe")})
```